# populate a select with data from the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I need to fill in a select with data from the bank. I have a description field and a category field, I need django to fill the select with the categories when opening the registration form.

I recently started using django and have been facing this difficulty. Does anyone have a light at the end of the tunnel?

cadproduto.html

```
   <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Categoria:</label>
                            <select class="form-control select" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                {% for categoria in ListaDeCategorias %}
                                <option value="{{categoria.id}}">{{categoria.descricaocategoria}}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import CadastroProduto

class ProdutoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CadastroProduto
        fields = ('descricaoresumida', 'precoprincipal', 'enviabalanca')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def ListagemCategorias(request):
    ListaDeCategorias = models.CadastroCategoria.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'listagemcategorias.html', {'ListaDeCategorias': ListaDeCategorias})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms


class CadastroProduto(models.Model):

    STATUS = (
        ('Ativo','Ativo'),
        ('Inativo','Inativo'),
    )

    descricaoresumida = models.CharField("Descrição Item", max_length=120)
    enviabalanca = models.BooleanField("Enviar p/ Balança", default=False)
    aliquota = models.CharField("Alíquota",                 max_length=20)
    codcategoria = models.CharField("Categoria",            max_length=8)
    unidademedida = models.CharField("Unidade de Medida",   max_length=3)
    ncm = models.CharField('N.C.M.',                        max_length=12)
    codsetor = models.CharField("Setor",                    max_length=8)
    codsubcategoria = models.CharField("Sub-Categoria",     max_length=8)
    precoprincipal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    ativo = models.CharField(
        max_length=7,
        choices=STATUS,
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descricaoresumida

class CadastroCategoria(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Ativo','Ativo'),
        ('Inativo','Inativo'),
    )

    descricaocategoria = models.CharField("Descrição Item", max_length=120)
    
    ativo = models.CharField(
        max_length=7,
        choices=STATUS,
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descricaocategoria
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pull select form options from database in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429228/pull-select-form-options-from-database-in-django)

Comment: Can you show the models?

Comment: @McPherson I added the post description to models.py

Comment: @markwalker_ I will check

Comment: @markwalker_ I tried using the example but got no results. I placed the items in a list but they do not appear in the select. =/

Comment: I was successful through this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6azHN4znW4&t=254s